# How to make <audio> play after turning on loop

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, loops, audio

I am working on a simple web audio player. I have copied and pasted the HTML and JS below, but can't include the audio files, so to see the working example, check out the GitHub page: [jsejcksn.github.io/audio-player/](http://jsejcksn.github.io/audio-player/)

Everything works like I want it to except I've noticed a problem, where it won't play under a certain condition in Chrome desktop (40.0.2214.91, on OS X). I've also tested on Safari desktop (8.0.2, on OS X) and Chrome on iOS, and it works fine on those. Here are the steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Press the `Play` button to play the audio file all the way through to the end (until it stops)
2. Press the `Loop` button
3. Press the `Play` button (It doesn't play!)

Is there a problem with my JavaScript? (That seems more likely than a bug in Chrome desktop, but I'm not sure.)

```js
// Variables ----------

var player = document.getElementById('player');
var btnLoop = document.getElementById('btn-loop');
var btnReplay = document.getElementById('btn-replay');
var btnPlayPause = document.getElementById('btn-play-pause');


// Functions ----------

function endOfAudio() {
 btnPlayPause.innerHTML = 'Play';
 console.log('Music stopped');
 }

function loop() {
 if (player.loop == true) {
  player.loop = false;
  btnLoop.innerHTML = 'Loop';
  console.log('Looping off');
  }
 else if (player.loop == false) {
  player.loop = true;
  btnLoop.innerHTML = 'Turn off Loop';
  console.log('Looping on');
  }
 }

function playPause() {
 if (player.paused == true) {
  player.play();
  btnPlayPause.innerHTML = 'Pause';
  console.log('Music playing');
  }
 else if (player.paused == false) {
  player.pause();
  btnPlayPause.innerHTML = 'Play';
  console.log('Music paused');
  }
 }

function replay() {
 player.currentTime = 0;
 player.play();
 btnPlayPause.innerHTML = 'Pause';
 console.log('Music playing from start');
 }


// EventListeners ----------

btnLoop.addEventListener('click', loop);
btnPlayPause.addEventListener('click', playPause);
btnReplay.addEventListener('click', replay);
player.addEventListener('ended', endOfAudio);
```

```html
<header>
 <h1>Audio Player</h1>
</header>

<div id="app">
 <audio id="player" controls preload="auto" src="audio/audio.mp3"></audio>

 <button id="btn-replay">Replay</button>
 <button id="btn-play-pause">Play</button>
 <button id="btn-loop">Loop</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the `ended` property of the audio player, [cf. here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_ended.asp). If the current playback has reached its end before the loop button is pressed, you can reset `currentTime` just like in your replay function, then play.

Comment: Do you mean adding an additional conditional for `ended` inside my `playPause` function, and then, if true, copy and paste the code from the `replay` function?

Comment: It seemed that would definitely have fixed the problem, but it didn't and I don't know why. Are you on a PC by chance or do you have an Android phone? I tried this in Safari desktop and it's also not a problem. Could you possibly test it in IE or Chrome Android? I'm beginning to wonder if this is a bug in the `<audio>` implementation of Chrome desktop.